# KafkaIO uneven partition consumption after a while

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a simple dataflow pipeline (job id 2018-05-15_06_17_40-8591349846083543299) with 1 min worker and 7 max workers that does the following:

1. Consume from 4 Kafka topics using KafkaIO. Each topic is represented differently and is a separate PCollection
2. Perform transformation on each PCollection to output a standard representation PCollection.
3. Merge the 4 PCollection using `Flatten.pCollections`
4. Window into hourly with the following trigger:

   ```
   Repeatedly
   .forever(
     AfterFirst.of(
       AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(40000),
       AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(5))
     )
   )
   .orFinally(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow())
   ```
5. Write these events to GCS using AvroIO windowed writes with 14 shards.

When the pipeline is launched initially everything is fine, but after several hours later, the System Lag increases dramatically in the AvroIO:GroupIntoShards step.

Upon further investigation one of the topics is lagging behind many hours (this topic has the greatest events per second when compared to the other 3). Looking at the logs I see `Closing idle reader for S12-000000000000000a` which is understandable. However, the topic's consumer group offsets for the 36 partitions is in a state where for some partitions the offset is very low, but some are very high. The log-end-offset is more or less evenly distributed and the records we are producing are around the same size.

Questions:

- If the System Lag is high in a certain step, does that prevent the Kafka consumers from consuming?
- Any possible reason for the uneven distribution in Kafka offsets?
- The PCollection's that is merged have different traffic patterns, some low and some high. Would adding the `AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(5)` trigger effectively start writing to GCS for each (window, shard) after 5 minutes when an event is first seen in a window?

Updating the pipeline using the same code / configuration brings it back into a normal state where the consumed rate is much higher (due to the lag before the restart) than the produced rate.

Comment: The job seemed to have worked well till 06/16 00:35 PDT. Everything stalled after that. I could only look at some metrics. Could you raise a support ticket, which allows better access (worker logs, etc)? This is likely an environmental issue (VM or disk issue or some other bug). Please check 'shuffler' logs in StackOverflow. 
After you updated the pipeline it looks like it did well and consumed all the backlog. So it is likely some VM specific issue, which got mitigated after update.

Comment: Correction : that is 05/16 00:36 PDT, and you already mentioned that update helped. That implies there was something unexpectedly wrong with the earlier pipeline.

Comment: How are you keeping track of offsets consumed? Did you enable offset commit / commitOffsetsInFinalize()? Btw, the whole topic is lagging, or only some partitions in the large topic were lagging behind. When I talked about skew in my answer below, I was referring to uneven consumption among partitions of a single topic.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I'll create a support ticket.

I've enabled commitOffsetsInFinalize. After further observation all the partitions for that large topic was lagging. 

Interestingly I've modified my pipeline to do a reshuffle before writing to gcs and the problem still happens but less often. The system lag is low in every step, but for some reason that topic is lagging ~ 3 hours and logs keep printing closing idle reader and initializing the reader. Autoscaling was not triggered. In the shuffler logs i noticed 'Current memtable full; waiting'

Comment: 'Current memtable full; waiting' implies I/O bottlenecks. All the symptoms mentioned point to severe slow down in the pipeline (possibly due IO bottlenecks, which can be improved with SSDs). Do you have the ticket id by any chance? You can look stackdriver metrics for some of the VMs during this time. Autoscaling does is not triggered when CPU consumption is very low (< 20%) since it usually implies increase number of workers does not help (like in this case, since I/O band-width is tied to PD size and number of PDs is fixed).

Comment: The case number is 15875156. We are using a non-default network and our firewall rule seems to be incorrectly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing 3 questions raised (I left a comment about the specific job):

1. No, system lag does not prevent Kafka from consuming.

   - In general if there is lots of work for downstream stages ready to be processed, that can delay upstream work from starting. But that is not KafkaIO specific.
2. Does not seem to be the case here. In general, assuming there is no skew among Kafka partitions themselves, heavy skew in Beam processing can cause readers assigned to workers that are doing more work than others.
3. I think yes. I think `firstElementInPane()` applies to element from any of the sources.